# Python importerror : pyqtconfig

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to install and run Eric4. I get the following error message when i try to open Eric after installation. Could anyone please let me know how to proceed?

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2013-07-31, 15:18:59
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: 
cannot import name pyqtconfig
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\eric4\eric4.py", line 295, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\eric4\eric4.py", line 207, in main
    Startup.setLibraryPaths()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\eric4\Utilities\Startup.py", line 195, in     setLibraryPaths
    from PyQt4 import pyqtconfig

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Numbers:
  Python 2.7
  Qt 4.8.4
  PyQt4 4.10.2
  sip 4.14.7
  QScintilla 2.7.2
  eric4 4.5.8 (r4410)

Platform: win32
2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for my poor English. After some googling I found that in Pyqt 4.10 and above, pyqtconfig.py seems be removed. Please check http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/build_system.html#module-PyQt4.pyqtconfig

I added a pyqtconfig.py and sipconfig.py get from web.

After that Eric4 starts (with some errors). Haven't do many operations in the editor yet.

Comment: if you build PyQt4 from source, pyqtconfig is installed when you use `configure.py`, but not when using `configure-ng.py`. On some Linux distros it can be in a separate package (`python-qt4-dev`).