# How to use KDE Okular's document view widget in a Python Qt app?

Tags: python, pyqt, kde-plasma, pykde, okular

I am writing a desktop application in Python (3.4) on Linux using Qt (4.8) and PyQt.

Is there a way to use/import Okular's pdf view functionality as a widget? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
import sys
from PyKDE4.kdecore import ki18n, KAboutData, KCmdLineArgs
from PyKDE4.kdecore import KLibLoader as ll
from PyKDE4.kdeui import KApplication
import PyKDE4.kparts as kp


appName     = "KApplication"
catalog     = ""
programName = ki18n ("KApplication")
version     = "1.0"
description = ki18n ("KApplication")
license     = KAboutData.License_GPL
copyright   = ki18n ("(c) 2007 John Doe")
text        = ki18n ("none")
homePage    = "www.johndoe.com"
bugEmail    = "johndoe@nowhere.com "

aboutData   = KAboutData(
    appName, catalog, programName, version, description,
    license, copyright, text, homePage, bugEmail
)

KCmdLineArgs.init(sys.argv, aboutData)

app     = KApplication()
win     = kp.KParts.MainWindow()
okupart = ll.self().factory('okularpart').create()
win.setCentralWidget(okupart.widget())
win.show()

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score -1):

**pykde** *could* provide the required functionality. I have not figured out how, though.

---

Get the latest version of pykde:

```
git clone git://anongit.kde.org/pykde4
```

Documentation: 
https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Python 
http://api.kde.org/pykde-4.3-api/install.html

Building it required PyQt4 and CMAKE. Some linux distributions ship an outdated version of FindPyQt.py (causing an error along the lines of [Python importerror : pyqtconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967542/python-importerror-pyqtconfig)). A functional one can be found here: 
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/cmake/FindPyQt.py 
Place it in /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/

For compiling your UI files into Python code, use pykdeuic4 instead of pyuic4:

```
pykdeuic4 file.ui > file.py
```