# Using okular in a Python app : hiding the side pannel

Tags: okular, pythonqt

I am developing a program ([TeXamator](https://github.com/alexisflesch/texamator)) in Python to deal with exercises databases in LaTeX. Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974374/how-to-use-kde-okulars-document-view-widget-in-a-python-qt-app/33345958) I have been able to successfully embed okular into my Qt app.

The problem is that I can't find how to access the sidebar and hide it. If I open okular, press F7 to hide/show the side bar and then go back to my app, then the side bar will be hidden/shown depending on its status when closing okular.

I've tried looking at the code of "okularpart" but I can't find anything useful.

Could someone please point me in the right direction ?

Thanks in advance.

Edit : after going through okular's source code, I understand that I should set the visibility of "m_toolbar" to False, but I don't know in which namespace it is (and if it is even accessible).
I've tried hiding each child of okupart.widget() (one by one), it hid a few things but not the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect to find it in the configuration list (since it's reachable by *Settings->Navigation panel*), so it won't be a widget. An alternative solution would be also to make it as small as possible.

Try to use something like

```
okupart.sidebar().setSidebarVisibility(false)
```

Check [Sidebar::setSidebarVisibility](https://github.com/KDE/okular/blob/c1e60e5539a4e2776bb97ad3d6e4e311cc904730/ui/sidebar.cpp#L649) and [this](https://github.com/KDE/okular/blob/c1e60e5539a4e2776bb97ad3d6e4e311cc904730/part.cpp#L578) corresponding call.

Comment: Thanks but that's where I'm stuck : I've been trying to dir() almost everything and can't find a "sidebar" in the different namespaces